# Importing picture from camera to computer in Windows 8 photo app

Tags: windows-8

After I choose my device to  import from (my camera) I DO NOT get the file name line with  the blue "import" box and black "cancel" box on the bottom of the screen. The line that allows you to name the file just does not show up at the bottom of my screen. Thank you for any help you can offer this slightly-technical person.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer you question directly, but when I import pictures from my Camera into Windows 8.  I just use the File Manager (Windows Explorer).  The Camera just appears as a new Device with a drive letter. I expand this and go to the DCIM Folder where all the pictures are stored, they just drag them to the My Pictures Folder.
I have found that some of the Windows 8 Apps just do not work that well or work differently then Windows 7.